# How can I add a slowdown effect when object is getting close to a target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Waypoints : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> waypoints = new List<Transform>();
    public float movementSpeed = 5.0f;
    public float slowdownSpeed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float waypointDistance = 0.1f;
    public float slowdownDistance = 7f;
    public bool moveBackward = false;
    public bool moveLoop = false;
    public bool includeTransformPosition = false;

    private Transform targetWaypoint;
    private int targetWaypointIndex = 0;
    private int lastWaypointIndex;
    private bool includeTransform = true;
    private GameObject go;
        
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        go = new GameObject();
        go.transform.position = transform.position;

        if (moveBackward && waypoints.Count > 2)
        {
            lastWaypointIndex = 0;
            targetWaypoint = waypoints[waypoints.Count - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            lastWaypointIndex = waypoints.Count - 1;
            targetWaypoint = waypoints[targetWaypointIndex]; //Set the first target waypoint at the start so the enemy starts moving towards a waypoint
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (includeTransformPosition && includeTransform)
        {
            waypoints.Insert(0,go.transform);
            includeTransform = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (includeTransformPosition == false)
            {
                waypoints.Remove(go.transform);
                includeTransform = true;
            }
        }

        float movementStep = movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        float rotationStep = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 directionToTarget = targetWaypoint.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion rotationToTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToTarget);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotationToTarget, rotationStep);

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetWaypoint.position);
        CheckDistanceToWaypoint(distance);

        if(slowdownDistance < 7f)
        {
            movementSpeed -= movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetWaypoint.position, movementStep);
    }

    void CheckDistanceToWaypoint(float currentDistance)
    {
        if (currentDistance <= waypointDistance)
        {
            targetWaypointIndex++;
            UpdateTargetWaypoint();
        }
    }

    void UpdateTargetWaypoint()
    {
        if (targetWaypointIndex > lastWaypointIndex)
        {
            targetWaypointIndex = 0;
        }

        targetWaypoint = waypoints[targetWaypointIndex];
    }
}
```

At this part I'm trying to slowdown the movement speed but it's not changing the speed at all :

```
if(slowdownDistance < 7f)
            {
                movementSpeed -= movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
```

What I'm trying to do when the transform start to move increase the speed slowly to some constant speed and then when the transform is getting closer to the waypoint then if the distance is less then 7 decrease the speed down to 0 so the object will stop at the waypoint then after X seconds move back the transform to the transform original position(go.transform) with the same increasing decreasing speed movement.

but I can't even make the first simple slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

you set slowdownDistance to 7, i dont see you ever reducing it below 7 but you have if statement that executes only it it is under 7 do you reduce it elsewhere?
You probably planned to compare  slowdownDistance to some distance rather than comparing it to its own value.

Comment: Right , the first problem is that I had to make the check like this : if(distance < slowdownDistance) the problem now is that the transform is slowing down too fast and the transform stop almost when it start slowing down and I wanted it to slow down until reaching the waypoint and stop at the waypoint so the slowing down will end at speed 0 when reaching the waypoint. Is there a  way to calculate how long it should slowdown to get to 0 speed when reaching the waypoint ? If for example starting slowdown from distance 10 or 7 or 4 in all cases the slowdown should end when reaching the waypoint.

Comment: You can make a " slowdown factor" instead of just slowing down directly and in calculating that factor make a division by distance.That way the larger the distance the smaller decelerating factor would be , reaching maximum deceleration at distance 0(and you need to do it the way its not doing so at distance 0).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to slow down the whole scene you could use a:

```
while(distance < range)
{
   Time.timeScale = 1 - (distance / value);
}
```

with this you can change the value and so when the player come close time will be slown down mostly.
With the same idea you can do:

```
while(distance < range)
{  
   speed = speedInitial - (distance / value);
}
```

If you want to change just the speed of the player